# I have a DNS server lookup that works but curious to know how

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008

I was able to get my IIS server to resolve the DNS entries for my application if I left the "DNS suffix for this connection" blank or if keyed in the primary domain. I though this was a fallback in case my primary domain was not found based on the article - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959322.aspx

So if I put in any incorrect value in there it should still work if my primary DNS servers in the "DNS server addresses, in order of use" was available.

Could someone please explain this scenario. I wasn't able to understand the technote from microsoft

[image: Advanced TCP/IP Setting page]

Added from reply:

I also got some more info from a networking guide. I usually leave the DNS suffix for this connection blank but it is best to put in the domain and check the "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration". This would help register any changes in the DNS registration of this machine/server.

Comment: "DNS suffix for this connection" only affects what happens if you try to resolve an unqualified DNS name, i.e., `mycomputer` instead of `mycomputer.mycompany.com`.  Your choice of DNS server(s) only affects whether you can resolve DNS names at all.  Two quite different things.

Comment: Thanks Harry makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I also got some more info from a networking guide. 
I usually leave the DNS suffix for this connection blank but it is best to put in the domain and check the "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration". This would help register any changes in the DNS registration of this machine/server.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13323657)

Comment: well, this was sort of the answer to the question but so i marked it in the answer section but @Bart if it needs to be in the question then that's okay